# Where the database should be with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a project that I didn't made which uses hibernate to connect to a database. I found the config file of hibernate in this project : hibernate.cfg.xml and it says :

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/persystddo</property>
<property name="connection.username">something</property>
<property name="connection.password">something</property>
```

I have an error when I try to run the project about hibernate. So I think that my database is not at the right place. So where should I put the database, in which folder ?
Thanks.

EDIT :

Exception : 500 - Transaction not successfully started

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException; transaction not successfully started
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:183)
    fr.inra.grignon.persyst.web.servlet.DoLogin.doPost(DoLogin.java:67
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.Server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
```

Comment: i don't know if it causes the problem but in the second line you're missing an "="

Comment: @ParkerHalo Thanks but it's just that I rewrite the code from an other computer, my bad !

Comment: @Gimby I'm not asking for the error message but just where I have to put the database.

Comment: @Gimby Why ? I don't understand what you mean :/

Comment: @Gimby Please help me

Comment: @Gimby I edited my post with the error

Comment: You need to ensure your MySQL server is installed and running properly in your local machine.

Comment: @user3247481 I'm using XAMPP so, I have mySQL installed and I can access it with phpmyadmin and I can see my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/persystddo

Please make sure that you have a database named "persystddo" exists in your mysql db. And the port is correct.
After that, also check you can login the database by username/password: something/something

Comment: Thanks ! The database "persystddo" is in "c:\xampp\mysql\data". Is it the right place ? When I go on my phpmyadmin, I can see it.

Comment: The password wasn't correct, so I changed it and it "works". I have a new exception but not the same! Thanks :)